# Creating an external Maven packaging POM

Tags: maven, deployment

It seems like common practice to create a packaging POM that packages and sets up the deployment environment for submodules within a project.
However is it possible to create a packaging POM outside of a project that can add functionality to it's deployment process?

I'm dealing with a situation where I have to make use of an in-house Maven project that builds up a web server with a default web service that provides certain functionality. I want to be able to build a custom version of that project that adds an additional web service to the container and tweaks the default configuration (without checking into that projects code repo).

Is this something that is supported by Maven or do I have to hack something together to make this type of deployment process work?

Comment: Are you talking about making like a parent project of an already existing parent? Because in that case the answer is yes

Comment: Yes but I still want the existing project to go through its build steps, and then add additional functionality after that build is complete. In this case, what does my "additional functionality" POM have to have? Do I have to define the existing parent project as a submodule? ie:

`<modules
   <module>../path/to/existing/project/existing-project</module>
  <modules>`